# How to stop the auto refresh function with java scripts after receiving some results from a thread

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I am developing some web application, with java scripts and servlets.

On the web application, a thread works at the background and a page should be refreshed automatically until the threads returns some results.

I would like to know how to stop the auto refresh after receiving some results.

Please see my codes.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#load_latest').load('./PubRecommendation' + ' #load_latest');
    }, 2000);
    </script>
    <div id="load_latest">
    if (result == null) {
            \\ while result equals null, the auto refresh should work
    } else {
            \\ after receiving some result, the auto refresh should be stopped
    }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer on your question: use clearInterval method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (result == null) {
        \\ while result equals null, the auto refresh should work
} else {
        clearInterval(auto_refresh);
}
</script>
```

But it seems you use API incorrectly. Try to load data with this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#load_latest').load('./PubRecommendation' + ' #load_latest', function($response, $status, $xhr) {
        alert("Load was performed: " + $response);
    });
</script>
```